# How do I add a value to a key without deleting the previous value in the key?

Tags: python

This is what I have so far:

```
newlines = []
diction = {}
i = 0
w = 0

f = open('file1.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

while i <= len(lines)-1:
    newlines.append(lines[i].strip('\n'))
    i += 1

season= newlines[::2]
shows = newlines[1::2]
temp_list = []


while w <= len(season)-1 and w <= len(shows)-1:
    diction[season[w]] = shows[w]
    if '20' in diction:
        temp_list.append(shows[w])
        diction['20'] = temp_list
    w += 1

print(diction)
```

**Outcome**
{'20': ['Gunsmoke', 'The Simpsons', 'Will & Grace', 'Dallas', 'Law & Order', 'Murder, She Wrote'], '30': 'The Simpsons', '10': 'Will & Grace', '14': 'Dallas', '12': 'Murder, She Wrote'}

**Desired Outcome**
{'20': 'Gunsmoke', 'Law & Order', '30': 'The Simpsons', '10': 'Will & Grade', '14': 'Dallas', '12' : 'Murder, She Wrote'}

**What file1.txt contains**
20
Gunsmoke
30
The Simpsons
10
Will & Grace
14
Dallas
20
Law & Order
12
Murder, She Wrote

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Python.

Comment: practically, you can't make a single dict key to multiple keys; otherwise what should `a = my_dict["30"]` do? .. though there are implementations of it; perhaps you want to put a list into your dict? `{'20': ['Gunsmoke', 'Law & Order'], '30': ..` you can also iterate directly by-lines over the file-like returned from `open()` .. for `line in f:...`

Comment: The standard solution to your problem is to use a dictionary in which each key maps to a list of items matching the key.  Remember, it's just a data structure.  You get to interpret it the way you want.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, but the idea is that the key '20' has 2 values in it. I know it's not correct this is my first time working with dictionaries.

Comment: @ti7 Oh alright, I didn't know you couldn't add to it like that. Thank you.

Comment: A dictionary has exactly one object as value per key. The object can be `Ǹone` or a `Container` type though.

Answer (score 1):

I explained with comments.

```py
f = open('text1.txt')

# Firstly read the text file with splitlines to not struggle with \n
lines = f.read().splitlines()

diction = {}

print(lines)
# Iterate each line
# lines = ['20 Gunsmoke', '30 The Simpsons', '10 Will & Grace', '14 Dallas', '20 Law & Order', '12 Murder, She Wrote']
for line in lines:
    # We are splitting the line to take season count and series name
    # It split with white space so we should merge the series name after taking the season count
    # ex.  splitted_line = ['30', 'The', 'Simpsons']
    splitted_line = line.split()
    # ex. season_count = '20'
    season_count = splitted_line[0]
    # ex. series_name = 'The' + ' ' + 'Simpsons'
    series_name = ' '.join(splitted_line[1:])
    
    # We can check whether the key we have exist in dictionar or not
    if season_count in diction:
        # If we have the key in dictionary
        # First we should check it is a just string or array of string
        # ex. It can be {'20': 'Gunsmoke'}
        # We we can came with another series with same season count we should make it array
        # ex. {'20': ['Gunsmoke', 'Law & Order'] }
        # If we have already an array, we can just append it
        temp = diction[season_count]
        diction[season_count] = [temp, series_name] if isinstance(temp, str) else temp + [series_name]
    else:
        # If we have not key in dictionary we should add it to dictionary
        diction[season_count] = series_name

print(diction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default dict from the collections library

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = """20 Gunsmoke 
30 The Simpsons 
10 Will & Grace 
14 Dallas
20 Law & Order
12 Murder, She Wrote"""

data_dict = defaultdict(list)

for d in data.splitlines():
    split = d.index(" ")
    show = d[split+1:]
    season = d[:split]
    data_dict[season].append(show)

print(data_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'20': ['Gunsmoke ', 'Law & Order'], '30': ['The Simpsons '], '10': ['Will & Grace '], '14': ['Dallas'], '12': ['Murder, She Wrote']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do it while changing as little code as possible. To start with initialised a list for each key and then simply appended them using your for-loop. That way you don't have to hardcode checking for '20' existing

```
newlines = []
diction = {}
i = 0
w = 0

f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

while i <= len(lines)-1:
    newlines.append(lines[i].strip('\n'))
    i += 1
print(newlines)
season = newlines[::2]
shows = newlines[1::2]
temp_list = []

for s in season:
    diction[s] = []

while w <= len(season)-1 and w <= len(shows)-1:
    diction[season[w]].append(shows[w])
    w += 1
  

print(diction)
```

Outcome is the following (Uses lists for each key) :

```
{'20': ['Gunsmoke', 'Law & Order'], '30': ['The Simpsons'], '10': ['Will & Grace'], '14': ['Dallas'], '12': ['Murder, She Wrote']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for doing it in a way I could understand. Everyone else was using code I haven't seen before (Probably should've mentioned me being a beginner in the post). Just to make sure I actually understand, all your doing is creating an empty list for each key to later be added to by append() correct?

Comment: Wait could you explain the diction[season[w]].append(shows[w])?

Comment: Yes no worries, all its doing is adding the show to the corresponding key's list. So it starts off with having keys with each of the values of the seasons i.e 20,30,12 etc which corresponds to an empty list. All that line does is get the list at that key and then add the name of the show to it. So for Gunsmoke it will get key '20' and then append gunsmoke to the list. (Append means to join an item to the end of a list). It does this for each item until you get the output I showed earlier.